# How to add a hyperlink in a text file in ASP.NET using VB

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, text-files

I have tow pages, first one for displaying the data in the text file and the other one is to store the data. I want to save a site in the text file but when i display the data will be just text and I can't click it as a link. The code I post is when I write to a file in display page.

```
    Try
        Dim fs As String
        fs = Server.MapPath("Footer.txt")
        lblsplittext.Text = ""
        Dim filestream As StreamReader 
        filestream = New IO.StreamReader(fs)
        Dim readcontents As String = filestream.ReadToEnd()
        Dim textdelimiter As String = "#"
        Dim splitout = Split(readcontents, textdelimiter)
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To UBound(splitout)
            lblsplittext.Text &= splitout(i) & "<br>"
        Next
        filestream.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

        Dim str As String
        str = ex.Message

    End Try
```

If you have a different suggestion about how to read from a file or database (it doesnt matter from where for now) just keep in mine when i display them i just need to have hyperlinks among my text... Or can I write to html file instead of text file if so what is the difference i need to make to write to html. I really really need help here and i have done many searches but i found nothing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not totally clear on what you want to do.  Am I right in thinking that you want to read text from a file and write it to a web page, but insert a hyperlink in the middle of the text on display?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to read text from a file and write it to a web page with ability of inserting hyperlinks in the middle of the text.

Comment: When you say "ability of inserting hyperlinks", would it be the code that inserted the hyperlinks, or a user?  Because if the screen text needs to be editable by the user, you'll need an editor control.  There are several.

Comment: Why can't you save that `Footer.txt` as `Footer.html`? Then you can have all html formatting you need.

Comment: I need to be able to edit everything from the edit page and I dont want to use VS when I edit it. However, can write to footer.html from the edit page not from the Visual Studio?

Comment: Hans so can just deal with .htm just like .txt file in writing and reading wise?

Comment: I have tried your way that I replaced the footer.txt with footer.html but they r just the same. Any more idea would so helpful for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this.  One would be to use a series of dynamically-added `Label` controls.  Your `Hyperlink` control could simply be inserted between one `Label` control and the next.

Do you intend to retrieve information from your series of labels on postback?  (It would be redundant to do that, since you already know what the information is, but just in case.)  Using multiple controls would make that more complicated.  You could try one or more `Literal` controls, created dynamically and added as child controls to a `Panel` control.  Again, the `Hyperlink` control would be added at whatever time you need it.

Comment: I had it as an HTML at first but my boss wants to have the ability to edit it by himdelf so i cant write hard code in it. any suggestion?

Comment: I retrieve everything from one text box.

Comment: Is there more than one hyperlink?  Is the place to which the hyperlink will lead known in advance?  You could use the Wiki approach of using substitute characters for the hyperlink, like [Home] or [Products].  Then at display time you substitute in the actual hyperlink.

Comment: Also, I wouldnt know when my boss would insert a hyperlink to the text file or just a regular text.

Comment: Thinking about it:  your best bet might be to use an editor control, like CKEditor (http://ckeditor.com/).  This would let your boss edit the content with a fully-featured editor, and allow you to save it in whatever form (such as HTML) that's most convenient.

Comment: To sum up:  the weak link is the idea of saving the contents as a text file but preserving footing like hyperlinks.  Better to edit it online using an editor, so that the actual form in which the content is stored doesn't matter.

Comment: I have never heard of CKEditor. can u give a brief explain about it please?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21022/discussion-between-ahmedali-and-ann-l)

Comment: Hey Ann L., I have checked CKEditor and I can use it with MVC but I working on Web site. So, it is so hard to start over again with MVC.

Comment: @Ahmed Here's a page on using CKEditor with WebForms:  http://petermcintyre.com/topics/intro-to-ckeditor/

Comment: @Ahmed  Here's what looks like a very useful page from CKEditor's own documentation:  http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Integration_Beginners

Comment: I will check them out Thanks.

Comment: Hey Ann, you are genious. It is working great with the text file and now i will try to work it out with mdf database. I know will be hard to work it with database because Im using grids and i think I need to change alot of stuff. thank you so much and if you have any idea of how to work it out with database please let me know.

Comment: Hi Ann, Im trying to integrate CKEditor with an MDF database. Do you any idea how? or do you know a website that can lead me? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @Ahmed Hi, Ahmed:  Why don't you post a new question and list the things you've tried, etc. Thanks.

Comment: I did listed but I didnt get any help yet so I thought you would a better help since you introduced me to CKEditor.